# adapter.setNotifyDatachanged() is not working as expected in android

Tags: android

This is my code file.

```
public class FragmentOfferList extends ListFragment {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private String TAG = FragmentOfferList.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final String endpoint = "http://example.com/offer/offers.json";
    private List<Offer> offers = new ArrayList<>();
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;

    public FragmentOfferList() {
    }

    public static FragmentOfferList newInstance(int num) {
        FragmentOfferList f = new FragmentOfferList();

        // Supply num input as an argument.
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("num", num);
        f.setArguments(args);

        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_list, container, false);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        adapter = new MyAdapter(offers, getActivity());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getActivity(), recyclerView, new ClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, int position) {
                Offer offer = Utility.getOffers().get(position);
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ActivityProductList.class);
                intent.putExtra("query", offer.getQuery());
                startActivity(intent);

                //startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), ActivityProductList.class));
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {

            }
        }));
        if (Utility.getOffers().size() == 0){
            fetchOffers();
        }
        else{
            Utility.displayToast("here");
            offers = Utility.getOffers();
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        return v;
    }

    public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

        private List<Offer> offers;
        private Context context;

        public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            public TextView title, year, offer;
            ImageView imageView;

            public MyViewHolder(View view) {
                super(view);
                imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
                title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
                offer = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.offer);
            }
        }

        public MyAdapter(List<Offer> offers, Context context) {

            this.offers = offers;
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.card_offer, parent, false);

            return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
            Offer offer = offers.get(position);
            holder.title.setText(offer.getName());
            holder.offer.setText(offer.getOffer());
            Glide.with(context).load(String.valueOf(offer.getUrl()))
                    .error(R.drawable.placeholder)
                    .thumbnail(0.5f)
                    .crossFade()
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                    .into(holder.imageView);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return offers.size();
        }
    }

    private void fetchOffers() {

        pDialog.setMessage("Downloading json...");
        pDialog.show();

        JsonArrayRequest req = new JsonArrayRequest(endpoint,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                        pDialog.hide();

                        offers.clear();
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            try {
                                JSONObject object = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                Offer offer = new Offer();
                                offer.setOffer(object.getString("offer"));
                                offer.setName(object.getString("name"));
                                offer.setUrl(object.getString("url"));
                                offer.setQuery(object.getString("query"));
                                offers.add(offer);

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                            }
                        }

                        Utility.setOffers(offers);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                pDialog.hide();
            }
        });

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req);
    }
}
```

First time when Utility.getoffers().size() is 0, it fetches data, save it in Utility.setOffers(offers) and display on screen as expected. But next time (go back and to same activity),   Utility.getoffers().size() is not 0 , i got data directly from Utility.getBrands().

After that i called adapter.notifyDataSetChaned(), but it is not working. Not working menas even though data sise is more than 0 but no data rendering on screen?

What is wrong here? am i missing anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not updating your `offers` list, but rather replacing it with another list that your adapter has no reference to. To fix this you can do the following:

```
offers.clear();
offers.addAll(Utility.getOffers());
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```